# Springboot logback configuration

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I tryng to configure my springboot app to log in one file for day so I configure my logback.xml just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="ROLLIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLIN" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

So when I try to run my app I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLIN] - No encoder set for the appender named "ROLLIN".
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at br.com.lumera.Application.main(Application.java:29)
:bootRun FAILED
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As exception says, there is no encoder defined. Try something like

```
  <appender name="ROLLIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

For more details see official [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please explain what this is doing with an [edit].

Comment: Why this dependency? What will it do?