# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

Logback is throwing me below error in my spring boot app

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:16 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:53 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:92 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:49 - no applicable action for [RollingFile], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:28 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][PatternLayout]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:26 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][PatternLayout][pattern]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:23 - no applicable action for [Policies], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:59 - no applicable action for [SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies][SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:50 - no applicable action for [DefaultRolloverStrategy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][DefaultRolloverStrategy]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@20:14 - no applicable action for [Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@21:29 - no applicable action for [Root], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:46 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:42 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@25:76 - no applicable action for [Logger], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@26:44 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger][AppenderRef]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@27:40 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger][AppenderRef]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@29:68 - no applicable action for [Logger], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@30:44 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Logger][AppenderRef]]
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:308)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.`enter code here`context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)

My logback configuration is:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:home}/logs/log"
            filePattern="${sys:home}/logs/mylog-%i.log" bufferedIO="false"
            immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p [%t] %c{1.} %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"></AppenderRef>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"></AppenderRef>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.myproj" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"></AppenderRef>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks like you have incorrect syntax of logback configuration. Refer to https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I think this topic will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892410/springboot-logback-configuration

Comment: I got this error when I specified an inaccessible log file location.

Answer (score 18):

This is probably log4j2 configuration. And to support it your Spring Boot pom file must be updated as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See more details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging (section 8.2 Configure Log4j for Logging).

Comment: Had the same problem dealing with logback. For me, adding the implementation dependency for the current version worked without setting an exclusion.

Comment: @MMascarin - may you please explain what was done in detail? I am getting this issue since last 3 days and not able to resolve :/ Please help

Comment: I think I just tried mp31415's solution (of just separately declaring spring-boot-starter-log4j2) and realised that I actually don't need the exclusion for it to work.

Comment: this saved my starter project, thank you very ,much

Answer (score 1):

The error can be resolved by using

```
<appender name="Console"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
```

instead of

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
```

[Link for reference](https://mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/)

Below is the reference how you can do it :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan = "true">

        <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
        <property resource ="application.yml"/>
        <springProperty name="NAME" source="spring.application.name" />
        <appender name="Console"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>
                    %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
                </Pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        
        <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/${NAME}.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.ms" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver" level="trace" additivity="true">
    </logger>

</configuration>
```