# LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - No destination was configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I've tryng to run a subscriber in Java in a Pub-Sub system. I keep getting hit with this error despite trying all solutions I've seen online.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@75ed9710 - Could not invoke method addDestination in class net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender with parameter of type java.lang.String java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - No destination was configured. Use <destination> to add one or more destinations to the appender
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:206)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.idrica.goaigua.asset.start.Runner.main(Runner.java:35)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my logback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <!-- local profile logs to stdout -->
    <springProfile name="local">

        <appender name="STDOUT"
                  class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>
                    %green(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}) %magenta([%thread]) %blue(%-5level) %yellow(%logger{36}) - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>

    <!-- not local profile logs to logstash -->
    <springProfile name="!local">

        <appender name="LOGSTASH"
                  class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
            <destination>${LOGSTASH_URL}</destination>
            <encoder
                    class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
                <providers>
                    <mdc/>
                    <context/>
                    <version/>
                    <logLevel/>
                    <loggerName/>
                    <message/>
                    <pattern>
                        <pattern>
                            {
                            "appName": "@service.name@",
                            "serviceName": "@service.name@",
                            "profileName": "${PROFILE}",
                            "type": "logback"
                            }
                        </pattern>
                    </pattern>
                    <threadName/>
                    <stackTrace/>
                </providers>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

I tried several solutions I've seen online such as:

[Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990948/getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-logback-configuration-error-detected-er)

https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/361

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender&method=addDestinations

And nothing works for me.

Comment: I guess `LOGSTASH_URL` is empty in `<destination>${LOGSTASH_URL}</destination>`. Have you tried setting the URL there to check it out?

Comment: Placing "${LOGBACK_URL:- }:${LOGBACK_PORT:- }" inside the "destination" tag makes the app to compile but unable to connect to anywhere, showing me this:

https://gyazo.com/bcd0308df52ed0425dc2d541dacc5848

Comment: The error confirms that those 2 are empty. Not sure how you want them to be set but can confirm that it doesn't work. Are they supposed to be env variables?

Comment: Yes, both are in config.env file.

Comment: And how is it read from this file? naming a file .env doesn't mean it will be read without doing anything...

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've solved this problem by adding "spring.profiles.active=local" to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use application.yml:

```
logstash:
    destination: your.tcp.address:8080
```

If you use application.properties:

```
logstash.destination: your.tcp.address:8080
```

and in your logback-spring.xml, you are missing:

```
<configuration debug="false">
  <springProperty name="LOGSTASH_URL" source="logstash.destination"/>
```